# Найти НОК для всех чисел из файла

Tags: c++, файлы, числа

Есть файл, в нём написаны числа. Нужно найти и вывести на экран самое маленькое число, которое делится на все числа из файла, тобишь наименьшее общее кратное. Я написала следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
/* Файл: числа. Найти и вывести на экран самое маленькое число, которое делится на все числа из файла */


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int num, min=1000000;
    ifstream f("in.txt");
    while(!f.eof()){
        f>>num;
        for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++){
            if (i%num!=0) break;
            else if(i<min){
                min=i;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<min<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Программа выдаёт 0. Что не так?

Comment: Возможно искомое число больше 1000000.

Comment: @Эникейщик навряд ли, у меня в файле забиты 2 3 4 5
Только что стёрла 2 числа, оставила 2 и 3, всё равно 0

Comment: Начните for-цикл с 1 - ``for (int i=1...``

Comment: @Эникейщик теперь выдаёт 1000000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все работает, как написано - на первом же шаге условие `if (i%num!=0)` не срабатывает, и min обнуляется

Для правильного же нахождения НОК можно задать его `tempnok = 1`, и далее обычным школьным методом (с использованием НОД) обновлять его на каждом шаге.

```
для всех чисел из файла:
   tempnok = NOK(tempnok, num)
```

**Edit:** Исправление к свежему ответу - достаточно этого:

```
 while(!f.eof()){
      f >> num;
      tempnok = NOK(tempnok, num);
 {
```

Есть и другие варианты - например, разложить все числа на простые множители и использовать произведение максимальных степеней этих множителей (для этого придется еще вести список этих множителей со степенями)

Comment: то есть, нужно будет написать отдельную функцию, считающую НОК?

Comment: Да, он считается как `нок=a*b/нод(a,b)`.

Comment: Лучше как `(a/НОД(a,b))*b` - немного меньше шансов получить переполнение :)

Comment: @Harry  Хотел поругаться, что вдруг нацело не разделится, но через две секунды передумал ;-)

Comment: :) Бывает и не такое...

Answer (score 1):

Исправила код, теперь вообще программа виснет...Кажется, я только хуже сделала:(

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
/* Файл: числа. Найти и вывести на экран самое маленькое число, которое делится на все числа из файла */
int NOD (int a, int b)
{
    while (a != b)
    {
        if (a > b)
            a -= b;
        else
            b -= a;
    }
    return a;
}

int NOK (int a, int b)
{
    return a * b / NOD (a, b);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int a, count=0, tempnok=1;
    ifstream f("in.txt");
    while(!f.eof()){
        f>>a;
        count++;}
        int num[count];
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){
        f>>num[i];
            tempnok = NOK(tempnok, num[i]);


    }
    cout<<tempnok<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я использовал num[i] в примере, чтобы показать, что работа идёт в цикле с каждым числом. В данном же ответе ошибка - входной поток считает числа и упёрся в конец файла, так что дальше ввод в массив уже не идёт. Можно для потока сделать clear и seekg на начало, но лучше уберите массив и смотрите добавление в моём ответе.

Comment: @MBo, блин, а ларчик просто открывался!:) что-то я реально всё слишком усложнила с этим массивом...спасибо Вам за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Никаких проверок на переполнение не производится. Если числа большие, можно использовать библиотеку gmplib (GNU arbitrary precision library). Компилится и собирается как натуральный C, так и как натуральный С++ код.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef unsigned long long int uint_t;

uint_t gcd(uint_t a, uint_t b);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: prog file\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    FILE *ifs;
    if (NULL == (ifs = fopen(argv[1], "r"))) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        exit(errno);
    }

    uint_t a;
    uint_t b;
    // читаем первое число (не проверяя ни на что)
    fscanf(ifs, "%llu", &a);
    // читаем и обрабатываем остальные числа
    while (1 == fscanf(ifs, "%llu", &b)) {
        a /= gcd(a, b);
        a *= b;
    }

    printf("НОК: %llu\n", a);

    return (0);
}

// Алгоритм Евклида
uint_t gcd(uint_t a, uint_t b) {

    if ((a == 0LLU) || (b == 0LLU)) {
        return 0;
    }
    uint_t c;
    if (a > b) {
        for (;;) {
            c = a % b;
            if (c == 0) {
                return b;
            }
            a = b % c;
            if (a == 0) {
                return c;
            }
            b = c % a;
            if (b == 0) {
                return a;
            }
        }
    } else if (a < b) {
        for (;;) {
            c = b % a;
            if (c == 0) {
                return a;
            }
            b = a % c;
            if (b == 0) {
                return c;
            }
            a = c % b;
            if (a == 0) {
                return b;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return a;
    }

}
```